# How to config `flutter attach --app-id com.example.id` in VSCode?

Tags: ios, flutter, vscode-debugger

**What am I doing?**

I have a native iOS app with an integrated Flutter add-to-app module. In order to debug the dart code, I launched the native app in an iOS Simulator, then I ran flutter attach to attach the Flutter debugger to the native app.
Below is my launch.json file.

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "chope_app_flutter",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart"
        },
        { 
            "name": "chope_app_flutter (iOS attach)",
            "request": "attach",
            "type": "dart"
        },
    ],
}
```

**What is the problem?**

Sometimes, when I start debugging flutter attach, some errors occur.

```
There are multiple observatory ports available.
Rerun this command with one of the following passed in as the appId:

  flutter attach --app-id com.example.id
  flutter attach --app-id com.example.id (2)
```

I know it's ok to run this in the terminal, but I want to debug flutter code in VSCode.

Can someone help to resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into a similar issue and solved it as follows:

```
// launch.json
{
  // ...
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "chope_app_flutter",
      "request": "attach",
      "type": "dart",
      "args": ["--app-id", "com.example.id"]
    }
  ]
  // ...
}
```

Assuming that the first app-id is really the one you want to attach to.

For more info on VSCode's `launch.json`, see [their docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes).